# How to send selected data from a dropdownlist to the corresponding table in mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

So this what I have done so far :

```
 //inserting enrolment details
string input_club = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
string enrol_mysql = "INSERT INTO enrolment_details(child_id,club_name) VALUES (@child_id, @club_name)";
long id = newchild.LastInsertedId;
MySqlCommand enrol = new MySqlCommand(enrol_mysql, connection);
enrol.CommandText = enrol_mysql;
enrol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child_id", id);
enrol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@club_name", input_club);
enrol.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem occurs when if for example user selects the club, the correct option does not appear on the table. (please look at the screen shots I have inserted)

[image]

[image]

EDIT: This has been called on a button click :

```
protected void registerEventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    registerUser();
    Server.Transfer("~/Registration_Login.aspx");
}


private void registerUser()
{...}
```

Additionally the options shown in the dropdownlist are retrieved from another table. Here is the code if for any relevance :

```
// Retriving club data from club_detail table from mysql
MySqlCommand clubdata = new MySqlCommand("SELECT club_id,club_name FROM club_details", connection);
DropDownList1.DataSource = clubdata.ExecuteReader();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "club_name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "club_id";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: `DropDownList1.DataValueField = "club_id";` shouldn't this be 
`DropDownList1.DataValueField = "enrolment_no";` if not can you show what the DataGridView Template looks like also where are you calling the `connection.Open()` command..?

Comment: also when populating the dropdown I would change that to load from a SqlDataAdapter I will post an example

Comment: EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the table i have used to display the options in the dropdownlist :http://i.stack.imgur.com/wDbwm.png.

Comment: check the edit this should still work..

Comment: When you run it in debug mode what is the value of the `SelectedItem.Text` property? also check the `SelectedValue` value to compare.

Comment: Please show the code where the method is getting called. Is it on click? on selected change? etc.

Comment: Don't use `Server.Transfer` use `Response.Redirect("~/Registration_Login.aspx");` instead also put break points in the `Page_Load` event and use `F12` Developer tools from the web browser.. you are probably getting some errors that are not showing up on the rendering of the pages postback

Comment: @SoniaMathews were you able to get your code to work ?

Comment: I was able to get rid of the errors but no whenever I choose a club from the drop down list, the table displays 'select item' instead of the club name ...

Answer (score 0):

```
var sqlQry = "SELECT club_id,club_name FROM club_details";
var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQry, connection);
var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "ClubDetails");
DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ClubDetails"];
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "club_name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "club_id";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Item", "0"));
```

you may also want to change this `string input_club = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;`
to test off of

```
var input_club = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: what errors are you running into .. I tried the same thing with a different query basically pulling back ID field and Name and works perfectly fine..

Comment: @SoniaMathews you need to put the word var infront of ds this should have been obvious but I will update for you hold on also change the way that you are doing your connection string and add entries into a `Web.Config` file don't hard code usernames and passwords in your code read them directly from the `<connectionStrings>` section of your config file

Comment: ok thankyou, However I still seem to be left with one more error where 'connection' is highlighted red....Argument 2: cannot convert from 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to 'string'

Comment: @SoniaMathews lets discuss [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101226/sonia-issues)

Comment: ok sure but unfortunately i am a first time user of this website forum and it says ' You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.'

Comment: I need a way to get your code so I can edit it to work properly @SoniaMathews